# Microsoft graphAPI onlineMeetings application routes return "unknown error"

Tags: oauth-2.0, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

When calling the Microsoft graphAPI application route: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user@example.com}/onlineMeetings?$filter=joinWebUrl eq '{joinUrl from invitation}'

I get an http 404 (not found) with a body like:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "UnknownError",
        "message": "",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2023-08-15T20:06:35",
            "request-id": "933fxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxx",
            "client-request-id": "933fxxxx-xxxxxxxx-xxxx"
        }
    }
}
```

I know there is data for this user and event, because I can call the equivalent delegated route successfully (logged in as user@example.com):

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onlineMeetings?$filter=joinWebUrl eq '{joinUrl from invitation}'

Gives the expected response.

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('xxxxx')/onlineMeetings",
    "value": [
        {
            "id": "MSozYmQyNGQ1Ni0xxxxx",
            "creationDateTime": "2022-10-25T14:14:32.3007696Z",
            "startDateTime": "2023-01-09T20:00:00Z",
            "endDateTime": "2023-01-09T20:30:00Z",
            "joinUrl": "https://teams.microsoft.com/l/meetup-join/xxxx",
            "joinWebUrl": "https://teams.microsoft.com/l/meetup-join/xxxx",
            "meetingCode": "1234567890",
            "subject": "some meeting",
            "isBroadcast": false,

           ....<snip>
```

**Why does the application route not return data?**

*Context*

In the Microsoft Entra Admin center, I've granted the application all the related permissions for onlineMeetings:
[image]

I've created and applied an `Application Access Policy` as indicated in [ms graphAPI docs for onlineMeeting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/onlinemeeting-get?view=graph-rest-1.0) using `New-CsApplicationPolicy`. I first granted that policy globally using `Grant-CsApplicationPolicy`. I believe that is when the delegated endpoints began working. I tried granting the policy to a specific user, but that did not change the application endpoint behavior.

I could not find a way to see what policy is granted to what user, but I can see that it is assigned to at least one user because `Remove-CsApplicationPolicy` complains that the policy is assigned when I try to remove the policy.

I read [This similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57929685/microsoft-graph-api-code-unknownerror), but the error code from that question is 503.

I'm using postman, but the MS graph explorer gave the same result.

*Why can't you use the delegated endpoints?*

The delegated endpoints use the OAuth2 "Auth code flow". The system I'm working with is non-iteractive. It is similar to zapier. Technically it is possible to implement the authentication dance, but it would be quite opaque and unmaintainable. I could implement a couple aws lambdas with a SAM api as opposed to a low code pipeline. However *neither* solution should be necessary if the application endpoints work!